# How come there are no categories for a videoId?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I try to use YT API Explorer to get all video categories for a videoId.

How come I get empty item array?

Any other way to get the video category for each video?

I saw there is `video.categoryId`. Is this the same? How do I translate this id to a string?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the official docs, the parameter [`id`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list#id) of [`VideoCategories.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list#id) API endpoint has a meaning that is contrary to your own understanding of it:

> [**`id`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list#id) (string)
> The `id` parameter specifies a comma-separated list of video category IDs for the resources that you are retrieving.

By this specification, `id` cannot be the ID of a given YouTube video.

Usually, one needs a category ID when uploading a video to YouTube. That's because the [`Videos.insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) API endpoint [requires the API user to specify the category ID](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#request-body) of the video to be uploaded.

Therefore, one would use `VideoCategories.list` for to obtain the list of all categories available under the region code specified through the [`regionCode`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list#regionCode) parameter:

> [**`regionCode`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list#regionCode) (string)
> The `regionCode` parameter instructs the API to return the list of video categories available in the specified country. The parameter value is an [ISO 3166-1 alpha-2](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists/country_names_and_code_elements.htm) country code.

Then the API user will pick one of the IDs returned by `VideoCategories.list` for to pass that on to `Videos.insert` as the value of the property `snippet.categoryId` that is part of the [video resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource) that he/she will pass on to the latter API call as HTTP request body.

---

If you're interested to obtain the video category that a given video belongs to -- let's say your video is identified by the ID `VIDEO_ID` --, then you'll have to call the [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) API endpoint passing to it `VIDEO_ID` as the value of the parameter [`id`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#id), for to look, within the video resource retrieved from the API, for the value of the property:

> [**`snippet.categoryId`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet.categoryId) (string)
> The YouTube [video category](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list) associated with the video. You must set a value for this property if you call the `videos.update` method and are updating the [`snippet`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet) part of a `video` resource.

Please acknowledge that any given video has attached precisely one video category ID (that specified by `snippet.categoryId`); thus any given video belongs to one and only one video category.

Comment: Thanks, so how can one get the videoCategory list for a given Video?